# Why do I get 'malformed input request' when invoking a Bedrock model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-bedrock

I'm trying to invoke Bedrock via curl, using this command:

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://bedrock-runtime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/model/cohere.command-text-v14/invoke' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'X-Amz-Content-Sha256: op' \
--header 'X-Amz-Date: 20231104T081154Z' \
--header 'Authorization: 0-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=/20231104/us-east-1/bedrock/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=' \
--data-raw '{
  "inputText": "Hi",
  "textGenerationConfig": {
    "maxTokenCount": 4096,
    "stopSequences": [],
    "temperature": 0,
    "topP": 0.9
  }
}'
```

I get the below error:

> Malformed input request: 3 schema violations found, please reformat your input and try again.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Amazon Titan Model's input for the Cohere Command Model, hence the schema error.

Your request `body` is [for Titan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/model-parameters.html#model-parameters-titan). You can tell this by the `inputText` field which is unique to this model's inference input. However, you've specified `cohere.command-text-v14` as your model ID i.e. Cohere.

Referring to the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/model-parameters.html#model-parameters-cohere), the below will work for the Cohere model, with the equivalent parameters set from your Titan input.

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://bedrock-runtime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/model/cohere.command-text-v14/invoke' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--user "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID":"$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" \
--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-east-1:bedrock" \
--data-raw '{
  "prompt": "Hi",
  "temperature": 0,
  "p": 0.9,
  "max_tokens": 4096
}'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "generations": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "COMPLETE",
      "id": "95e12e0f-aa3e-4812-8995-34d124b7354e",
      "text": " Hello! How can I help you today?"
    }
  ],
  "id": "e7fb4f46-a046-4fd5-9bc3-340eefc9007f",
  "prompt": "Hi"
}
```